# how can I apply gravity to my gameobject in flutters flame library

Tags: flutter, box2d, flame

I am having trouble applying gravity to a Rect object I want to fall freely along the Y-axis by updating Rect's position In my code with the body.position.y. Here is a snippet of my code :

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:box2d_flame/box2d.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';
import 'package:mimo/mimo-game.dart';

class Mimo {
  final MimoGame game;
  CircleShape shape;
  Body body;
  List<Sprite> mimoSprite;
  List<Sprite> deadSprite;
  double flyingSpriteIndex = 0;
  Rect mimoRect;
  bool isDead = false;
  bool isOffScreen = false;

  Mimo(this.game, double x, double y) {

    shape = CircleShape(); //build in shape, just set the radius
    shape.p.setFrom(Vector2.zero());
    shape.radius = .1; //10cm ball

    BodyDef bd = BodyDef();
    bd.position = new Vector2(x,y);
    bd.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
    body = game.world.createBody(bd);
    body.userData = this;


    FixtureDef fd = FixtureDef();
    fd.restitution = 0.5;
    fd.density = 0.05;
    fd.friction = 0;
    fd.shape = shape;
    body.createFixtureFromFixtureDef(fd);


    mimoSprite = List();
    mimoSprite.add(Sprite('mimo/mimo-1.png'));
    mimoSprite.add(Sprite('mimo/mimo-2.png'));
    mimoSprite.add(Sprite('mimo/mimo-3.png'));
    mimoSprite.add(Sprite('mimo/mimo-4.png'));
    mimoSprite.add(Sprite('mimo/mimo-5.png'));
    deadSprite = List();

    mimoRect = Rect.fromLTWH(body.position.x, body.position.y, game.mimoSize, game.mimoSize);
  }

  void render(Canvas c) {
    mimoSprite[flyingSpriteIndex.toInt()].renderRect(c, mimoRect.inflate(2));
  }

  void update(double t) {

    mimoRect = mimoRect.translate(body.position.x, body.position.y);
  }
}
```

in the `update` method I use the line `mimoRect = mimoRect.translate(body.position.x, body.position.y);` so the body.position can update my `Rect` object in real-time. but nothing happens as my spawned object is always fixed at a position and does not move. I decided to log `body.position.y` to the console and noticed it does not change.

In my main class, I create a world object like this :

```
 //Needed for Box2D
  static const int WORLD_POOL_SIZE = 100;
  static const int WORLD_POOL_CONTAINER_SIZE = 10;
  //Main physic object -> our game world
  World world;
  //Zero vector -> no gravity
  final Vector2 _gravity = Vector2(0, 4.0);


  Body body;
  CircleShape shape;
  //Scale to get from rad/s to something in the game, I like the number 5
  double sensorScale = 5;
  //Draw class
  Paint paint;
  //Initial acceleration -> no movement as its (0,0)
  Vector2 acceleration = Vector2.zero();



  MimoGame() {
    world = new World.withPool(_gravity,
        DefaultWorldPool(WORLD_POOL_SIZE, WORLD_POOL_CONTAINER_SIZE));
    initialize();
  }
```

Please any idea on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Box2DGame` (flame 0.22.0^) class in flame for your game and the object that you want to apply gravity to needs to extend `BodyComponent`, then you create an instance of your `BodyComponent` in your `Box2DGame` and use the `add` function to add it to the game loop which will make sure that `update` and `render` is called on it every iteration.

There is a good example in the flame source [here](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/master/doc/examples/box2d/contact_callbacks).

Also remember that if your gravity is positive, your object will be flying upwards.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @DavoudBadamchi it is now called forge2d, you can find examples of how to use it toghether with flame here: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/tree/main/packages/flame_forge2d/example